# The Little Schemer: `lat?` without `cond`?

Tags: scheme, the-little-schemer

One of the first questions in the second chapter of The Little Schemer (4th edition) asks the reader to write the function `lat?`, where `(lat? l)` returns true if `l` is a list of atoms.

It goes on to say:

> You were not expected to be able to do this yet, because you are still missing some ingredients.

But I'm familiar with recursion, and the definition of `atom?` earlier in the book already introduced `and` (further implying the existence of `or`), so I gave it a shot anyway: ([repl](https://repl.it/repls/PointlessFrostyGavial))

```lisp
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (or
      (null? l)
      (and
        (atom? (car l))
        (lat? (cdr l))))))
```

On the next page, the book introduces the `cond` operator to enable this definition of `lat?`:

```lisp
(define lat?
  (lambda (l)
    (cond
      ((null? l) #t)
      ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l)))
      (else #f))))
```

Is there any significant difference between these two implementations?

Comment: no. except for the actual, not implied, existence of `or`; which that `cond` expression is defining, effectively.

Answer (score 1):

`cond` is a special form, that takes (roughly) the form

```
(cond
  ((test-expression) (then-expression))
  ((test-expression2) (then-expression2))
  (else
   (then-expression3)))
```

Its semantics is that it will evaluate the `test-expression`s in order, and for the first one that it finds to evaluate to `#t` (the `true` value), then it will evaluate its associated `then-expression` and return its value. If all the `test-expression`s evaluate to `#f` (the `false` value), and an `else` clause is present, then it will evaluate its associated `then-expression3` in this case, and return its value.

So as far as semantics are concerned, the two implementations are equivalent. Their only difference might be that afaik the `cond` version is considered more idiomatic in the Scheme community.